# castle.microkernel

Tags: c#

I am trying to get Castle.MicroKernel from this url http://www.castleproject.org/castle/download.html but I can not seem to find it in the latest zip file. please help.

I need Castle.MicroKernel and does any one know where I could find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of Windsor 2.5.1 AFAIK.